# Rebooting iPhone Doesn't Kill off All the Process

Tags: iphone

I tried to reboot my iphone according to the [guidelines](http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonehowtos/qt/turn_off_iphone.htm) here, but after the phone is started, I found that all the apps are still there at the bottom of the screen when I tap on the home button twice.

Any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only *real* way to be certain that you have killed apps off is to jailbreak.

Jailbreaking lets you install a piece of software called SBSettings, which includes a real task manager that lets you force-quit **any** app, *including* the Apple apps.

[image]

Jailbreaking is awesome for lots of other reasons too!
I got this picture off my iPad by starting the Samba daemon I have installed, and just browsing to the image using windows explorer.
No cable or iTunes needed,

Comment: Jailbreaking is terrible for lots of reasons, too. Best of luck with it.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick - Such as? Name some....

Comment: Bricking the device if the jailbreak fails. Breaking your warrantee, such that if you have a hardware problem and can't restore it to a non-jailbroken state before taking it to Apple, you'll pay full price for any repairs, even if they're due to a manufacturing defect. Apps run outside the sandbox on jailbroken phones, so they can do anything they want, including sending your personal information (including call records, all text messages, your email, many app passwords, etc.) to anyone. Malware disguised as cool apps. And much, much more.

Comment: Did you not look into it before jailbreaking?

Comment: Braking your warranty is a non-issue, you just flash to stock. As far as I know, no malware has made it into Cydia, and if you feel you can't trust Cydia, I don't see why you would trust the App Store, considering the irregularities in apple's screening process, and the numerous userland exploits used to break out of the sandbox to install jailbreak in the first place, which crop up regularly (If the sandbox was secure, jailbreaking would not happen in the first place). The fact that apps can do interesting things as root/privileged user is half of the *advantage* of jailbreaking.

Comment: I guess you missed the warranty part where I said "if you have a hardware problem and can't restore it." I understand the advantage of jailbreaking, that something is an advantage doesn't mean it isn't a disadvantage, too. Crazy, right? And no, I do not even *remotely* trust the Cydia **security screening process** the way I do the App Store's. They don't even compare. All of that said, this is no place for a big jailbreaking discussion. I just wanted to point out to any naive readers that it's far from magical unicorn awesomeness. Feel free to continue, of course, but I'm done.

Comment: @Fake Jailbreaking also brings your battery life to a halt (if you go too coo-coo installing daemons and stuff). I have a couple of iPhone 2G and 3G that were jailbroken "for fun" and their battery lasts less. But I believe Matthew hit the nail. Jailbroken is "ok" but it's far from being "awesome".

Comment: Well, it's certainly "awesome" on the iPad.'

Comment: jailbreaking turns the iOS in what it should be from beginning - I doubt there's anyone who believes Jobs uses iOS with all those restrictions.

Comment: Interesting thread. Matthew makes a error in judgement, the app store is secure from anyone who's money Apple won't take. Right now, pretty secure.  2 bad quarters, Jobs passes away? Not so secure then. What I want from this device is to use it to the max. Like the computer it is, not the phone it pretends to be.  Now, carriers and (RI|MP)AA won't let that happen from apples standpoint.  No way.  I don't see things from apples standpoint however, I see them from mine.  I pay, it's mine. I brick, I pay again. Gotcha. Jailbreaking is the freedom to choose.  That is awesome.

Answer (score 10):

<s>As a developer I can assure you that if you reboot the phone, those apps are no longer running in any way. At that point it's literally just a list of apps that you've launched in the past in reverse chronological order.</s>

**Edited to note:** I've since verified (as @ughoavgfhw pointed out) that backgrounded apps can in fact have their services restarted after a reboot. You can still kill all non-Apple services using the method I describe below.

---

If you still don't feel comfortable, you can manually quit the apps any time. Simply double-press the home button to reveal the list of "running" apps -- the multitasking bar -- and tap-and-hold on one of them, the same way you rearrange you apps in Springboard.

They'll begin to wiggle, and instead of the black circle with an "x" in it that appears in the upper-left corner of each app icon (used to delete apps off the device entirely) you'll see a red circle with a "-" in it. Tap the red circle and the app will be completely forced from memory, killing an associated processes. After you've quit the first several, even if you haven't restarted your phone you're in the "totally suspended" territory.

Press the home button again to stop the wiggling, as normal.

[image: Deleting an App: Black Circle with x]
**Deleting an App: Black Circle with "x"**

[image: Quitting an App Red Circle with dash]
**Quitting an App: Red Circle with "–"**

[image: Empty app list after quitting all of them]
**Empty multitasking bar, all apps have been dumped**

Comment: Even after a reboot, some could be running. Apps which say they use certain background services can be restarted automatically when that service becomes available (I think location and voip do this).

Comment: This does **NOT** work with *all* apps. I closed the Mail app this way, and it is still present in the SBSettings task manager. Its possible Apple has special rules for their own apps, or that certain apps can circumvent this. It *did* work for several other apps I tried.

Comment: Ah, Mail probably is a special case, as are Messages (SMS) and Phone, which obviously keep running. I suspect that nothing will kill the Mail process permanently.

Comment: Yeah, I think the built-in apps tend to be able to do more stuff than App Store apps (including Apple’s App Store apps). That’s pretty much just based on vague memories of John Gruber saying things on The Talk Show though.

Comment: @Matthew: actually yeah — if the user could kill the Mail process, Settings.app would presumably have to switch the option for checking mail regularly to “Never”. That might not be what the user expected when they removed Mail’s icon from the app-switching list.

Comment: @Paul Exactly. The same is likely true of the Calendar app: suddenly my appointments aren't current, what the heck? The App Store app, too: why don't I get any of those updates anymore?

Answer (score 4):

> all the apps are still there at the bottom of the screen when I tap on the home button twice

I don’t think that means the processes aren’t killed off. As far as I know, the apps listed when you double-tap the home button are those that were most recently running, not necessarily those that are *currently* running.

See further two recent blog posts on the subject:

- http://speirs.org/blog/2012/1/2/misconceptions-about-ios-multitasking.html
- http://daringfireball.net/2012/01/ios_multitasking

Answer (score 4):

Very few of those apps actually have running processes, even if you don't reboot. Only if they're finishing a download, streaming audio, tracking your location or handling a VOIP call. Otherwise, they've just saved their session state, and have no running processes associated with them.

Answer (score -2):

I noticed the same thing myself a little while ago. This is annoying. Apple claims that the apps are in "stasis" and not eating processes, but I find that hard to believe that is true with EVERY app. Especially ones that are in the background waiting to alert you of something (like Skype telling you that you have an incoming call or a GPS app)

I really wish that a "hard reset" would clear out all the background apps but the ugly truth is that the operating system just doesn't work that way.

There is nothing you can do about this until Apple changes how this works with an OS-level update.

(p.s. When I took my iPhone an Apple store to get it looked at with a problem with the sleep wake switch, the Apple rep told me that he "cleaned out all the background apps" to make things run smoother. Which makes me think that these apps aren't working as exactly as we think that they are)

Comment: “I really wish that a "hard reset" would clear out all the background apps but the ugly truth is that the operating system just doesn't work that way.” — If by “hard reset” you mean “turning the phone on and off again”, then you’re saying you think third-party apps can launch at startup?

Comment: And if by “ugly truth” you mean “I wish Apple would let me inspect all the processes running on my phone’s CPU”, then I think you probably want a phone from another manufacturer. Apple’s entire design approach seems focused on hiding everything apart from the most high-level stuff from the user, and taking care of everything else automatically.

Comment: You are totally missing the point here.

Firstly, a "hard reset" is defined by the user holding down the home and sleep button (bypassing the red swipe bar) until the phone shuts off. 

Secondly, Apple isn't trying to hide the multi-tasking apps, in fact, THEY FLAUNT IT every chance they get. And they have been doing so since they released it.

What I am saying, is that instead of tapping my screen 20 times to close all the apps in the multi-task bar, there should be one button to clear them all at once. Or a "hard reset" should do it instead.

So, what the hell are you talking about?

Comment: @Alex: Sorry, I didn’t phrase that well. I meant their philosophy is that the user only needs to know they can switch back to apps really quickly. Whether each app is still running isn’t something Apple wants the user to have to think about — hence the app switching list isn’t a list of running apps. As far as Apple’s concerned, apps will stop running in the background when necessary, no user intervention required. This is why Apple doesn’t have, and [mocked the need for](http://www.engadget.com/2010/04/08/jobs-if-you-see-a-stylus-or-a-task-manager-they-blew-it/), a task manager.

Comment: @Alex: Obviously it’s cool if you’d rather know exactly what’s going on with your pocket computer — on my Mac, I’ve got a bunch of monitoring stuff running in the menu bar. I’m just saying that Apple’s *entire* approach to their consumer products is focused on abstracting this stuff away, so if you’re waiting for them to change this (“until Apple changes how this works with an OS-level update”), you’re probably going to be disappointed, and you might want to consider an Android phone.

Comment: I've been using Macs for 10 years and the iPhone since the day it was released. I don't think I have to wait for an Android phone for this change. Mark my words, in iOS 5, there will be a change to the multi-task system and I bet you that they add the ability to close them all at once.

Comment: @Alex: me too. Fair enough, we’ll see; but I doubt that such an option would literally kill all background processes though, e.g. Mail and Messages.

Comment: Not to go all “I told you so”, but iOS 5 hasn’t added a “close all” option to the multitasking bar. [John Gruber’s recent post](http://daringfireball.net/2012/01/ios_multitasking) does a good job explaining why.